# How can I use Docker and Verdaccio, publish a package, then share that Docker Image to another person with the Package showing up?

Tags: docker, verdaccio

I have got the Verdaccio running with docker on my system using:

```
docker pull verdaccio/verdaccio
docker run -it --rm --name verdaccio -p 4873:4873 verdaccio/verdaccio
```

I can then see my Verdaccio at localhost:4873.
I add a user:

```
npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873/
```

I go to a simple package repo and publish it:

```
npm publish --registry http://localhost:4873/
```

I then go to the browser and see my package is in the list on localhost

I then rename my docker container:

```
docker rename 4d2b---3692 my-container
```

On docker hub I have a repo called `myuser/my-container`

I then commit my container

```
docker commit 93ba9d----e myuser/my-container
```

Then I push it to Docker Hub (I did log in already)

```
docker push myuser/my-container
```

I see that it is updated on my Docker Hub.

I remove everything related to Docker on my computer

```
docker rmi --force 93ba9d----e
```

I then see nothing when I run these commands

```
docker ps -a
docker images
```

Then I try and pull my container

```
docker pull myuser/my-container
```

I then run my container

```
docker run -it --rm --name verdaccio -p 4873:4873 myuser/my-container
```

I can then see the Verdaccio page on localhost:4873, however I can not see the published package.

Please let me know what I am missing, thanks.